# How can I make bash more readable?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

As a linux user, I spend a lot of time mucking about in bash. I've always been a bit frustrated by how poor the readability is.

Today this annoyed me enough to spur me into action. My immediate problem was solved by this snippet, which [changes the directories colour to magenta](http://www.geekgumbo.com/2011/11/04/changing-the-directory-color-in-the-bash-shell/). (Annoyingly, this caused me to lose all the other `ls` colours.)

So I started wondering, what other tweaks exists to make bash a bit more readable?

Comment: Maybe better on SuperUser? That aside, get a decent font for starters. Look for a font with a line height ~120% (0.2 of a line gap), makes it much more readable. In Gnome Terminal go to Edit->Profiles to change that stuff, I'm sure there's an equivalent in most other terminals but I mainly work with the Gnome one

Comment: The readability is what you set it to be. Nothing to get frustrated about, just configure to your liking.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz That's kinda the point of my question. I'm not blaming bash. I want to know how people have configured it to their liking.

Comment: If you come up with a specific attribute you want to change we can go with that, but "what stuff do you do to make bash readable" is [massively broad](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe Solarized? http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized

There's a bunch of projects that do similar terminal colorization schemes with an eye to usability.

Answer (score 4):

The other colors in `ls` output were gone, because the blog post you refer to gives really poor instructions. If you set `LS_COLORS` to `'di=0;35'`, then you've *just instructed* `ls` to color *only* directories. Remove that setting from your `.bashrc`, re-login in another terminal and do

```
echo "$LS_COLORS"
```

You'll probably see a long set of color settings. Here's what I have:

```
LS_COLORS="rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:\
bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=01;05;37;41:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:\
ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:\
*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:\
*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:\
*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:\
*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:\
*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:\
*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:\
*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:\
*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:\
*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:\
*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:\
*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:\
*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:\
*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:\
*.pdf=00;32:*.ps=00;32:*.txt=00;32:*.patch=00;32:*.diff=00;32:*.log=00;32:\
*.tex=00;32:*.doc=00;32:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:\
*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:\
*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36"
```

The useful property of that variable is that if you define a color more than once, the last setting will override any previous. So if you just want to change the color for displaying directories to magenta, do

```
export LS_COLORS="${LS_COLORS%:}:di=01;35:"
```

(A colon is used to separate settings.)